# Im only getting the username and password field? React

Tags: reactjs, api

Im trying to use post data but the only thing im getting back from the form is the username and password, What am i doing wrong?  i want to get the teacher data too inside the state like fname, lname, mname etc. Also why is it only the username and password is getting posted or serialized. Thanks so much in advance

```
class Teachers extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                selectedData: {},
                tableData: [{
                    id: '',
                    email: '',
                    password: '',

                }],
                username: '',
                password: '',
                teacher: [{
                    employeeNo:'',
                    prefixName: '',
                    fname: '',
                    lname: '',
                    middleInitial: '',
                    sex: '',
                    citizenship: '',
                    status: '',
                    permanentAddress: '',
                    presentAddress: '',
                    bday: '',
                    contactNo: '',
                    emailAdd: '',
                    emergencyContactNo: '',
                }],
            }

            this.editedData = params => {
                console.log(params);
            };

            this.toggleModal = this.toggleModal.bind(this);
            this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
            this.addNotification = this.addNotification.bind(this);
            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

        }
}


 handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
    };

    //request the token

    async handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const getCred = await fetch('http://tfismartasp-001-site10.btempurl.com/api/Teacher/Register', {
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'ApiKey': "Secret"
            },
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username: this.state.username,
                password: this.state.password,
                prefixName: this.state.teacher.prefixName,
                fname: this.state.teacher.fname,
                lname: this.state.teacher.lname,
                middleInitial: this.state.teacher.middleInitial,
                sex: this.state.teacher.sex,
                citizenship: this.state.teacher.citizenship,
                status: this.state.teacher.Status,
                permanentAddress: this.state.teacher.permanentAddress,
                PresentAddress: this.state.teacher.presentAddress,
                bday: this.state.teacher.bday,
                contactNo: this.state.teacher.contactNo,
                emailAdd: this.state.teacher.emailAdd,
                emergencyContactNo: this.state.teacher.emergencyContactNo,

            }),
        });


        const data = await getCred.json();

        console.log(data);
    }



<Modal isOpen={this.state.modalDialog} className="modal-lg" fade={false} toggle={() => this.toggleModal("modalDialog")}>

                    <ModalHeader toggle={() => this.toggleModal("modalDialog")}>
                        Edit Profile
                    </ModalHeader>
                    <form className="margin-bottom-0" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <ModalBody>

                        <h3><label className="control-label">Personal Information </label></h3>

                        <label className="control-label">Name <span className="text-danger">*</span></label>
                        <div className="row row-space-10">
                            <div className="col-md-2 m-b-15">
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Prefix" name="prefixName" value={this.state.teacher.prefixName} onChange={this.handleChange} required="" />
                            </div>

                                <div className="col-md-4 m-b-15">
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="First name" name="fname" value={this.state.teacher.fname} onChange={this.handleChange} required="" />
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-md-4 m-b-15">
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Last name" name="lname" value={this.state.teacher.lname} onChange={this.handleChange} required="" />
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-md-2 m-b-15">
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Middle name" name="middleInitial" value={this.state.teacher.middleInitial} onChange={this.handleChange} required="" />
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div className="row row-space-10">
                                <div className="col-md-4 m-b-15">
                                    <label className="control-label">Gender <span className="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                        <select className="form-control" name="sex">
                                        <option value={this.state.teacher.sex} onChange={this.handleChange}>MALE</option>
                                        <option value={this.state.teacher.sex} onChange={this.handleChange}>FEMALE</option>
                                        </select>
                                </div>

                                <div className="col-md-4 m-b-15">
                                    <label className="control-label">Birthdate <span className="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="date" className="form-control" placeholder="Birthdate" name="bday" value={this.state.teacher.bday} onChange={this.handleChange} required="" />
                                </div>

                                <div className="col-md-4 m-b-15">
                                    <label className="control-label">Citizenship <span className="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Citizenship" name="citizenship" value={this.state.teacher.citizenship} onChange={this.handleChange} required=""  />
                                </div>

                                <div className="col-md-4 m-b-15">
                                    <label className="control-label">Status <span className="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                        <select className="form-control" name="status" placeholder="status" >
                                        <option value={this.state.teacher.status} onChange={this.handleChange}>Single</option>
                                        <option value={this.state.teacher.status} onChange={this.handleChange}>Married</option>
                                        </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <hr/>




                            <h3><label className="control-label">Account Information </label></h3>

                            <div className="row row-space-10">
                            <div className="col-md-4 m-b-15">
                                <label className="control-label">Employee Number <span className="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Employee No." name="employeeNo" value={this.state.teacher.employeeNo} onChange={this.handleChange} required="" />
                                </div>

                            <div className="col-md-4 m-b-15">
                                <label className="control-label">Username <span className="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleChange} required="" />
                                </div>

                            <div className="col-md-4 m-b-15">
                                <label className="control-label">Password <span className="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} required="" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <hr/>

                            <h3><label className="control-label">Contact Information </label></h3>

                            <div className="row row-space-10">
                            <div className="col-md-4 m-b-15">
                                <label className="control-label">Permanent Address <span className="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Permamnent Address" name="permanentAddress" value={this.state.teacher.permanentAddress} onChange={this.handleChange} required="" />
                                </div>

                            <div className="col-md-4 m-b-15">
                                <label className="control-label">Present Address <span className="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Present Address" name="presentAddress" value={this.state.teacher.presentAddress} onChange={this.handleChange} required="" />
                                </div>

                            <div className="col-md-4 m-b-15">
                                <label className="control-label">Contact Number <span className="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Contact No." name="contactNo" value={this.state.teacher.contactNo} onChange={this.handleChange} required="" />
                                </div>

                            <div className="col-md-4 m-b-15">
                                <label className="control-label">Email Address <span className="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" name="emailAdd" value={this.state.teacher.emailAdd} onChange={this.handleChange} required="" />
                                </div>

                            <div className="col-md-4 m-b-15">
                                <label className="control-label">Emergency Number <span className="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Emergency No." name="emergencyContactNo" value={this.state.teacher.emergencyContactNo} onChange={this.handleChange} required="" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </ModalBody>
                    <ModalFooter>
                        <button onClick={() => {
                            this.addNotification('success', 'Success', 'All data has been successfully saved', 'bottom-right')
                            this.toggleModal("modalDialog")
                        }} className="btn btn-sm btn-success">Save</button>

                        <button
                            className="btn btn-white btn-sm"
                            onClick={() => this.toggleModal("modalDialog")} >
                            Close
                        </button>
                        </ModalFooter>
                        </form>
                </Modal>
```

Comment: Your state `teacher` is an `Array` but you use it as an `Object`, which cause undefined, and won't be handled by res/req

Comment: `this.state.teacher` is an array so you have to iterate/destruct it.

Comment: can you tell me how im new in react sorry

Comment: your `teacher` in the `state` is an array, so you cannot access values like `this.state.teacher.presentAddress`,  either you have to  access values like `this.state.teacher[0].presentAddress` or  declare teacher as object. eg in `this.state={
.....,
teacher:{
...
}
}`. Then you can access values like `this.state.teacher.prefixName`

Comment: @MichaelBenGabriel you are doing it in wrong way,  you are trying to `setState` in your `handleChange` function with a key that is not defined inside state, but inside `teacher` in `state`, either move it outside `teacher` in state or apply some other logic.

Comment: @AkhilAravind i  understand that but i need that the other inputs is isnide the teacher inside the state.

Comment: why you need that values inside the teacher object ? you can create a new object when you are passing values to backedn

Comment: @AkhilAravind because the api request is made like that state = { teacher:{} }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207518/discussion-between-akhil-aravind-and-michael-ben-gabriel).

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about only one teacher object, you can change the teacher to an object. Just remove `[` and `]` between the teacher object.

Comment: yes i tried that but when i remove the [ ] . my input field is disabled and i cant fill it up.omg im totally lost

Comment: If there is only one teacher object we are talking about, maybe try bringing all teacher information up to state level. like
`
this.state={username:'', password: '', teacherEmployeeNo: '', teacherPrefixName: ''}
`

Comment: but this is the api im fetching for post { "username": "string", "password": "string", "teacher": {
    "id": 0,"employeeNo": 0,"prefixName": "string","fname": "string","lname": "string",
"middleInitial": "string","sex": "string", "citizenship": "string",
  }
}

Comment: It would be much easier if you create a sandbox with your code from here https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Comment: @NabinAdhikari there is no need for sandbox, since the way he access data from state in incorrect. what is the point of fiddle here ??

Comment: im totally lost heres the sandbox if you can help me @NabinAdhikari https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-wave-onghv

Comment: @AkhilAravind can you help me whats wrong with my state

Comment: @MichaelBenGabriel, you are little bit confused with the state. It can be achieved with removing the teacher object. I have created a code sandbox for you. Check out here https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-burnell-7mi4z